# Internal server error code 500 when uploading a file to a directory with Flask

Tags: python, html, file-upload, flask, server

Here is the backend Flask code for a basic file uploading form

```
@app.route('/gallery',methods=['GET','POST'])
def gallery():

error = None
if request.method == "POST":
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash("No file part")
        return redirect(request.url)

    file = request.files['file']
    print file
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
    flash('file uploaded successfully')

return render_template('gallery.html')
```

And the HTML frontend code for the form:

```
<div class="page">
    <h2>Gallery</h2>

    <p>Upload image</p>
    <form action="{{ url_for('gallery') }}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit">
    </form>

</div>
```

I have the UPLOAD_FOLDER variable set to an /uploads directory on the root of my project in which I would like to Flask to store images, however every time I submit an image to upload I get a 500 error.

Strangely enough, if I upload the file to the root of my project directory instead I do not get an error. The error only occurs if I upload the file to my upload directory.

[Edit] Added traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/sitea-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/fred/personalsite/cool_site.py", line 70, in gallery
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2653, in save
    dst = open(dst, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/uploads/Lecture 1.pages'
```

Comment: Show us your traceback

Comment: assuming there is valid value in app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] and you have correct access rights to that path ... you code seems fine, can you tell the error when you run it in debug=True case

Comment: Sorry I'm so new to this, I just discovered how to use the debugger like 5 seconds ago. Here is the debugger error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/uploads/Lecture 1.pages' Lecture 1.pages is of course the name of the file I tried to upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your error says is that the folder does not exist. Create the folder `/uploads/` and make it readable for the program. 
If the folder should be relative to your Flask directory use 
 `uploads/` instead.

Comment: The directory does exist though.

Comment: That's weird because apart from that it looks correct. The only other issue I could image is this being an encoding error. You are trying to save it in a Unicode style directory which might be different from the default enconding on your system. Either try to convert the Unicode to a string or maybe follow the example here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/ --> filename = secure_filename(file.filename) maybe this fixes the issue

Comment: Ah perfect, I mean your solution is exactely what my other guess was.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was happening because my UPLOAD_FOLDER variable was set to /uploads when it should have been been set relative to the Flask directory (uploads/)